# Conservation for $u_t + cu_x = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

This question is about Exercise 3.6 (p. 73) of Miller's *Applied Asymptotic Analysis*, which asks:

> Let $u_0(x)$ be differentiable and suppose $\int_\mathbb{R} u_0(x)^2 \,dx < \infty$.  Show that whenever $u(x,t)$ is a smooth solution of the initial value problem
>   $$
> u_t + cu_x = 0, \qquad u(x,0) = u_0(x),
> $$
>   the integral
>   $$
> \int_\mathbb{R} u(x,t)^2\,dx
> $$
>   is independent of $t$.  Hint: begin by multiplying the PDE by $u$.

(The goal of the rest of the exercise is to prove existence and uniqueness of solutions for the PDE.)

Following the hint I multiply through by $2u$ to get

$$
2uu_t + 2cuu_x = (u^2)_t + c(u^2)_x = 0,
$$

then integrate with respect to $x$:

$$
\int_\mathbb{R} \left[ (u^2)_t + c(u^2)_x \right]dx = 0.
$$

Supposing that at least one of the terms is integrable I split it in two, so that

$$
\int_\mathbb{R} (u^2)_t\,dx + c \int_\mathbb{R} (u^2)_x\,dx = 0.
$$

Now I have the following questions:

> **1.** To show what is asked it seems necessary that
>   $$
> \lim_{x \to \pm\infty} u(x,t)^2 = 0,
> $$
>   since then
>   $$
> \int_\mathbb{R} (u^2)_x\,dx = 0.
> $$
>   This isn't implied by the assumptions as far as I can tell.  What can I do?
>
> **2.** How can I justify the interchange of integral and derivative:
>   $$
> \int_\mathbb{R} (u^2)_t\,dx = \frac{d}{dt} \int_\mathbb{R} u^2\,dx
> $$
>   ?  The usual justification I know would be to show that $|(u^2)_t| \leq f(x)$ for some integrable $f$, but this doesn't seem like it can be true in this case.
>
> (It fails for $u(x,t) = \exp[-(x-ct)^2]$, for instance.)

Answer (score 2):

1) Usually people impose the condition that $c > 0$. If this is also true for your case, do you see how 1) is resolved?

2) I'm a little embarassed that I haven't quite figured out how to do this in the way your book probably wants you (admittedly, I haven't looked at it to fairly say this). Nevertheless, here's a way of doing this.

a) Notice that the function $f(t,x) = u(t, x+ ct)$ satis $\partial_t f(t,x) = 0$ (why?), hence it's a depending solely on $x$, and in particular , by setting $t=0$, we must have $f(t,x) = u_0(x)$

b) By relabeling, we must have $u(t,x) = u_0(x - ct)$

c) $\int_{\mathbb{R}} u^2(t,x) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} u^2_0(x - ct) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} u^2_0(x) dx$

Where the final expression is finite (by the given) and independent of $t$.

Comment: I don't really see what assuming $c>0$ says in regards to 1).  Could you elaborate?

Comment: Ooh, wait, I made a mistake, let me reponder.

Comment: I take it back. Letting $c> 0$ doesn't do anything. I had mixed up my squares and derivatives. Nevertheless,  (assuming there are no more errors I've missed) the work for 2 doesn't depend on it.

Comment: I appreciate your method from 2), thanks :).  I'm not experienced enough to recognize whether it assumes uniqueness of the solution, but it sure doesn't seem like it.